# Operation private to two classes without friend functions

Tags: c++, oop, language-agnostic, friend

Consider two classes `Box` and `Rabbit` with a simple one-to-one relationship - box can contain up to one rabbit, and rabbit can sit in up to one box.

In pseudo code, we have the following interface:

```
class Box
  - getRabbit():Rabbit
  - putRabbit(rabbit:Rabbit)

class Rabbit
  - getContainingBox():Box
  - putIntoBox(box:Box)
```

Of course we want to maintain invariant: `box.getRabbit().getContainingBox() == box`, if `box` is not empty, and same for `rabbit`.

In C++, we can declare function `putRabbitIntoBox(Rabbit* rabbit, Box* box)` as friend for both `Box` and `Rabbit`, and implement `Box::putRabbit` and `Rabbit::putIntoBox` in terms of `putRabbitIntoBox`. And I don't see any major disadvantage with this method (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
class Box;
class Rabbit;
void putRabbitIntoBox(Rabbit* rabbit, Box* box);

class Rabbit {
public:
    Rabbit() :box(nullptr) {}
    Box* getContainingBox() { return box; }
    void putIntoBox(Box* box) { putRabbitIntoBox(this, box); }
private:
    Box* box;
    friend void putRabbitIntoBox(Rabbit* rabbit, Box* box);
};

class Box {
public:
    Box() :rabbit(nullptr) {}
    Rabbit* getRabbit() { return rabbit; }
    void putRabbit(Rabbit* rabbit) { putRabbitIntoBox(rabbit, this); }
private:
    Rabbit* rabbit;
    friend void putRabbitIntoBox(Rabbit* rabbit, Box* box);
};

void putRabbitIntoBox(Rabbit* rabbit, Box* box) {
    if (rabbit && rabbit->box) {
        rabbit->box->rabbit = nullptr;
    }
    if (box && box->rabbit) {
        box->rabbit->box = nullptr;
    }
    if (rabbit) {
        rabbit->box = box;
    }
    if (box) {
        box->rabbit = rabbit;
    }
}
```

Now we decide to implement the same `Box`/`Rabbit` thing, say, in Java (or C#, or whatever language with no `friend` functions).

Is there idiomatic way to address this problem?

I know that it can be solved by calling `putRabbit` from `putIntoBox` and vice versa, with some guard code, like so:

```
void Rabbit::putIntoBox(Box* box) {
    if (this->box == box) {
        return;
    }
    if (this->box) {
        Box* oldBox = this->box;
        this->box = nullptr;
        oldBox->putRabbit(nullptr);
    }
    this->box = box;
    if (box) {
        box->putRabbit(this);
    }
}
```

But it looks horrible to me. Instead of one function with one clearly defined purpose, we have a very error-prone recursive 'thing'.

Comment: If you don't have `friend` declarations, you provide public modifiers.

Comment: In your C++ example, you have three functions that all do the same thing. Why would you want that? Pick one (e.g. `Box::putRabbit`) and get rid of the other two. Simplifies the interface and also answers your question.

Comment: @Nemo, yes, in C++ I can do that by making `Box::putRabbit` a friend of `Rabbit` class, still I don't have a reason to prefer `Box::putRabbit` or `Rabbit::putIntoBox` in this case, that's why a separate third function. But in C# or Java, I can't access private state of `Rabbit` from `Box`.

Comment: @bku_drytt, with public modifiers I can't enforce mentioned invariant, so client code can eventually make multiple rabbits refer to the same box. Unless I use the described ugly recursive trick (and then `putIntoBox` and `putRabbit` are actually public modifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are:

1. Box can have one or zero Rabbit connected to
2. Rabbit can have one or zero Box connected to
3. If Box is connected to Rabbit, then Rabbit is connect to this very Box and vice  versa
4. Both Box and Rabbit are classes on the same level - you do not want to set one of them as owner of other...

So - just implement these constraints in Box and Rabbit. First thing - forget about defining setters and getters for everything - just implement functions you need - nothing more.

So - let's define the interfaces:

```
class Box;
class Rabbit {
public:
    ~Rabbit() { disconnect(); }
    void connect(Box* box);
    Box* getMyBox() const { return box; }
private:
    void disconnect();
    Box* box = nullptr;
};
class Box {
public:
    ~Box() { disconnect(); }
    void connect(Rabbit* otherRabbit);
    Rabbit* getMyRabbit() const { return rabbit; }
private:
    void disconnect();
    Rabbit* rabbit = nullptr;
};
```

As you can see - first two constraints are just met by defining one pointer in each classes to its mate class.

Sp the only left constraint is to ensure that two objects (Rabbit and Box) are either connected to each other - or not connected at all:

```
inline void Rabbit::connect(Box* otherBox)
{
    if (box != otherBox)
    {
        disconnect();
        box = otherBox;
        if (box != nullptr)
            box->connect(this);
    }
}

inline void Rabbit::disconnect()
{
    if (box != nullptr)
    {
        Box* oldBox = box;
        box = nullptr; // do this before calling disconnect on box - otherwise you get infinite recursion...
        oldBox->connect(nullptr);
    }
}
```

You have to define similar functions in `Box`. Working example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Vh8qoi)

In C++ you can use template - because as you can see - both classes are very much in the same way defined... Although I cannot say if templates will solve the same problem in other languages...

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your class design. In your example, putting a `Rabbit` into a `Box` changes the state of both classes. Generally, mutable state is something that should be avoided if possible. In this case, it would be acceptable if the `Box` changes its state, but why should the `Rabbit` too?

Having the same information in both classes can also lead to inconsistency.

Therfore I would only define:

```
class Box {
public:
    putRabbit(Rabbit r);
    Rabbit getRabbit();
...
}
```

The `Rabbit` class would not have any methods related to `Box`. You can still find out in which `Box` a `Rabbit` is if you have all boxes stored in some container where you implement a method like:

```
Rabbit r;
...
Box b = allBoxes.findRabbitBox(r);
```